# Is there a way for WordPress to read the TCPDF file inside the theme directory?

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress

I have finish parsing json to html table, and now I am going to get my html table generate to pdf using TCPDF. Everything is working on the local but when I apply it on WordPress, it seems that the WordPress didn't read the TCPDF file inside the theme directory.

How do I make my file to be read by WordPress?

Here's my complete code:

```
<?php                         
            
            ob_start();
            if (!isset($_POST['generate_pdf']))
            { 
            $askPriceBeds = '{"status":"success","postcode":"W14 9JH","postcode_type":"full","url":"https://propertydata.co.uk/draw?input=W14+9JH","bedrooms":2,"data":{"points_analysed":20,"radius":"0.09","average":657495,"70pc_range":[ 575000, 725000 ],"80pc_range":[ 550000, 875000 ],"90pc_range":[ 550000, 925000 ],"100pc_range":[ 525000, 950000 ],"raw_data":[ {"price":650000,"lat":"51.48887000","lng":"-0.20776000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.00" }, {"price":575000,"lat":"51.48884800","lng":"-0.20701200","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":615000,"lat":"51.48851000","lng":"-0.20742000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":640000,"lat":"51.48932000","lng":"-0.20804000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":725000,"lat":"51.48843100","lng":"-0.20775400","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":699950,"lat":"51.48928000","lng":"-0.20793700","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.03" }, {"price":550000,"lat":"51.48941000","lng":"-0.20832000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.04" }, {"price":600000,"lat":"51.48813700","lng":"-0.20781600","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.05" }, {"price":925000,"lat":"51.48948300","lng":"-0.20827400","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.05" }, {"price":650000,"lat":"51.48824900","lng":"-0.20669000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":700000,"lat":"51.48941200","lng":"-0.20666900","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":625000,"lat":"51.48817000","lng":"-0.20689500","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":645000,"lat":"51.48822500","lng":"-0.20872100","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":675000,"lat":"51.48877800","lng":"-0.20643200","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.06" }, {"price":525000,"lat":"51.48978800","lng":"-0.20864000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.07" }, {"price":700000,"lat":"51.48785100","lng":"-0.20757600","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.07" }, {"price":675000,"lat":"51.48819900","lng":"-0.20637900","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.08" }, {"price":875000,"lat":"51.48818700","lng":"-0.20931800","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.08" }, {"price":550000,"lat":"51.48891000","lng":"-0.20955000","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.08" }, {"price":950000,"lat":"51.48808300","lng":"-0.20628500","bedrooms":2,"type":"flat","distance":"0.09" } ] },"process_time":"2.08"}';

            $data = json_decode($askPriceBeds, true);

            $raw_data = $data['data']['raw_data'];
            ?>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Lat</td>
                            <td>Lng</td>
                            <td>Bedrooms</td>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Distance</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach($raw_data as $raw){
                        echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$raw['price']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['lat']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['lng']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['bedrooms']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['type']."</td>
                            <td>".$raw['distance']."</td>
                        </tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" value="Generate PDF">
                </form>
            </body>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/themes/property-investment-vault/tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php');
                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/themes/property-investment-vault/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
                
                $tcpdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
                
                $tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
                
                $tcpdf->SetTitle('');
                
                $tcpdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
                
                $tcpdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
                
                $tcpdf->setFooterFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
                
                $tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
                $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
                
                $tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
                $tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);
                $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);
                $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);
                $tcpdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
                $tcpdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
                $html = '<html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th> Price</th>
                            <th> Lat</th>
                            <th> Lng</th>
                            <th> Bedrooms</th>
                            <th> Type</th>
                            <th> Distance</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 650000</td>
                            <td> 51.48887000</td>
                            <td> -0.20776000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 575000</td>
                            <td> 51.48884800</td>
                            <td> -0.20701200</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.03</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 615000</td>
                            <td> 51.48851000</td>
                            <td> -0.20742000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.03</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 640000</td>
                            <td> 51.48932000</td>
                            <td> -0.20804000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.03</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 725000</td>
                            <td> 51.48843100</td>
                            <td> -0.20775400</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.03</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 699950</td>
                            <td> 51.48928000</td>
                            <td> -0.20793700</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.03</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 550000</td>
                            <td> 51.48941000</td>
                            <td> -0.20832000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.04</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 600000</td>
                            <td> 51.48813700</td>
                            <td> -0.20781600</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.05</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 925000</td>
                            <td> 51.48948300</td>
                            <td> -0.20827400</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.05</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 650000</td>
                            <td> 51.48824900</td>
                            <td> -0.20669000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.06</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 700000</td>
                            <td> 51.48941200</td>
                            <td> -0.20666900</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.06</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 625000</td>
                            <td> 51.48817000</td>
                            <td> -0.20689500</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.06</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 645000</td>
                            <td> 51.48822500</td>
                            <td> -0.20872100</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.06</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 675000</td>
                            <td> 51.48877800</td>
                            <td> -0.20643200</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.06</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 525000</td>
                            <td> 51.48978800</td>
                            <td> -0.20864000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.07</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 700000</td>
                            <td> 51.48785100</td>
                            <td> -0.20757600</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.07</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 675000</td>
                            <td> 51.48819900</td>
                            <td> -0.20637900</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.08</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 875000</td>
                            <td> 51.48818700</td>
                            <td> -0.20931800</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.08</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 550000</td>
                            <td> 51.48891000</td>
                            <td> -0.20955000</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.08</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 950000</td>
                            <td> 51.48808300</td>
                            <td> -0.20628500</td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                            <td> flat</td>
                            <td> 0.09</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
                </html>';
                $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
                $tcpdf->lastPage();
                ob_end_clean();
                $tcpdf->Output("datareport.pdf", 'FD');          
    }
?>
```

Comment: "it seems that the WordPress didn't read the TCPDF file" - Please elaborate. Also, please make sure that PHP and WordPress error reporting are enabled so that you can see any error messages. Be careful with `ob_start`, although it is totally valid to use, it can also hide errors sometimes.

Comment: I have checked my codes on local and it is running smoothly, but when I applied it to WordPress put all codes inside theme files including TCPDF but it always loads and there's no error occurring. So I guess the problem would be the file directory of TCPDF. What to do to make this work?